# Change specific values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have df like this:

```
Name   Value       NUM_SC

A      1000        421

B      2000        127

C      3000        511

D      2000        718

E      1500        511 (may duplicate)
```

And I would like to multiply some Values by (-1) based on their NUM_SC. For example, for 511 and 127 in NUM_SC multiply Value by (-1). What worked for me is:

```
for i in negative_sc:
    for j in range(76818):
        if df.NUM_SC[j] == i:
            df.Values[j] *= (-1)
```

where  *negative_sc* containts NUM_SC for which I would like multiply Value by (-1). In this example negative_sc = (511,127).

But this method takes a lot of time. I tried something like this:

```
for i in negative_sc:
   df[df.NUM_SC == i].Values *= (-1)
```

But this produced error and didn't yield any results.

What is the best way to handle tasks like this? Change values in one column based on values in another column

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not chain `[ ]` and `.column_name`. So both `df.Values[j] *= -1` and `df[df.NUM_SC == i].Values *= -1` don't work. See [this document](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing) for details.

Instead do:

```
df.loc[df.NUM_SC.isin(negative_sc), 'Values'] *= -1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, using [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) create a mask for columns you would like need to negate.

```
negative_sc = [511, 127]

mask = df['NUM_SC'].isin(negative_sc)

df.loc[mask, 'Value'] = df.loc[mask, 'Value'] * -1
```